# Huge (20 digits) Primary keys and SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, primary-key

If I try to insert data with a 20 digit primary key into a SQLite database I get an error with the second insert statement because it "is not unique".
If I select the values I can see from the SQLite commandprompt that the primary key is written in scientific notation. 
The column type is decimal. Is there a way to force SQLite to insert the values "as they are" keeping the precision / "normal representation" even with values that long?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

insert it as a 'string', not a number.

Comment: Well, I had to define the column as TEXT and insert the values quoted. I think this is because of SQLite's type-affinity

Comment: Steve, that is *so* cold. I have to remember that one.

Answer (score 3):

the primary key field must be an integer, the largest value is 9223372036854775807.  use a separate (indexed) field, and insert the value as string.

Comment: There is no requirement as to the primary key being an integer in SQLite. The rowid is a 64-bit integer, but that's a different matter altogether. The primary key can be any data type you like. See here for details: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 0):

Strange, sounds like your wrapper is putting the number in as a float. I thought DECIMAL was mapped to an integer internally. Using a string would work but may be slow do to the indexing of the string rather than an int.

Comment: DECIMAL has numeric affinity.  This means that any data type can be stored, but strings are converted to INTEGER or REAL if possible.  The OP probably declared an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column, which *does* require a 64-bit signed integer.